# Redux-Toolkit - how to pass the state to the Child Components

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I use redux to store my data in app. I am wondering about the method, how to pass the data from state to child components. What I know, in case useContext I create the Provider and can pull out the data in simple way like:

```
const myData = React.useContext(MyContext);
```

But I have no idea how to do the same trick in redux in an effective way. I know mapeStateToProps, but I hope there are easier ways.
Look at my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState, store } from 'redux/store';
import { IStep, changeValue } from 'redux/reducers/multiStepForm';   

import Stepper from './Stepper';
import Step from './Step';
import Controls from './Controls';

const MultiStepForm = (): JSX.Element => {
  const activeStep = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.multiStepForm.activeStep);
  const steps = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.multiStepForm.steps);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    dispatch(changeValue(e.target.value));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(
      'Form values',
      steps.map((step: IStep) => step.value)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: '0 200px' }}>
      <h2>MultiStep Form</h2>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} steps={steps} />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Step activeStep={activeStep} steps={steps} handleChange={handleChange} />
        <Controls activeStep={activeStep} steps={steps} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MultiStepForm;
```

So, as you can see, I pass the props from state to children (Stepper, Step, Controls). Each of them use the same props (activeStep and steps).

How to make it easier/smarter?

Let's take a look at one of the children as example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IStep, InitialMultiStepFormState } from 'redux/reducers/multiStepForm';
import { StepperLine, StepperNumber, StepperStep, StepperWrapper } from './Stepper.styled';

const Stepper = ({ activeStep, steps }: InitialMultiStepFormState): JSX.Element => {
  const stepNumber = (step: number) => step + 1;

  return (
    <StepperWrapper>
      {steps.map((step: IStep) => (
        <StepperStep key={step.id + 1}>
          <StepperNumber completed={step.id <= activeStep}>{stepNumber(step.id)}</StepperNumber>
          {stepNumber(step.id) === steps.length ? null : (
            <StepperLine completed={stepNumber(step.id) <= activeStep} />
          )}
        </StepperStep>
      ))}
    </StepperWrapper>
  );
};

export default Stepper;
```

Please about any advice or link with explanation.

Comment: What is the question? Is something not working?

Comment: @HMR it's working now. As I wrote, I wouldn't like to pass the data (activeStep, steps) as props like now. I imagine I do it in simplier way and I ask about the ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of React is to pass props to immediate child components. This is nothing to be avoided, this is what components and props were made for.

If you have to pass something multiple (>2-5) levels, you can just do the same `useSelector` calls (wrap them into a custom hook!) in those later components and pass nothing down in-between, but with immediate children, this is the way to go.

Even using context for that would likely be considered an antipattern. Before resolving to anything like context, you should have already tried props & composition, as context does not come for free either.